# how to register Fingerprint for Authentication on Nexus emulator

Tags: emulation, nexus-5

there is no response after I typed adb -s emulator-5554 emu finger touch 1. 
this is reference link 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog/issues/2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open Security Settings on your Fingerprint Emulation enabled Emulator.
According to [Android Developers Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html), Register 1 or 2 fingerprints with command

`adb -e emu finger touch 1`

or

`adb -e emu finger touch 2`

and save the settings. Next time when you are prompted for the Fingerprint Authentication again enter the same command

`adb -e emu finger touch 1`

to successfully authenticate. I just tried and it works fine.

Comment: link isn t actual.

Answer (score 0):

This is the command to add a "Virtual Fingerprint" 
`adb emu finger touch <fingerprint ID>` 
it is recommended to only run it with `-s <emulator-ID>` so you won't accidentally add a fake fingerprint to your real device.

If it's not working you should update your `platform-tools`. 
(and If you run Ubuntu make sure you **don't** install `android-tools-adb` because it's an older version)